# Display repeated tags in XSLT?

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I am working with a CV project using XML for storing CVs, using XSLT and Java to transform it to HTML.

Following is the format of XML file

```
<CVs>
<cv>
<name>...</name>
<dob>...</dob>
<experience>
<job>.....</job>
<job>.....</job>
</experience>
</cv>
<cv>
<name>...</name>
<dob>...</dob>
<experience>
<job>.....</job>
<job>.....</job>
<job>.....</job>
<job>.....</job>
<job>.....</job>
</experience>
</cv>
</CVs>
```

What is the right way to display the `<job>` repeatedly? I am getting only one `<job>` and that the first one...

Have a nice day
John

---

Thanks a lot for your reply. :)

I tried the first solution. It works. But what I what I want is to display all the  with a HTML paragraph formatting.

First display the  No.1, then there should be a paragraph, then  No.2 and so on. 
like-

```
<p>Job No1</p>
<p>Job No2</p>
```

I used following - with a failure to get the required result..

```
<xsl:for-each select="Job">
<p style="color:red">
<xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1">,</xsl:if>
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
</p>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Using the above code I am getting output like -

```
<p>Job No1 job No2..</p>
```

I am using XSLT 1.0, which I mention to forget in the first post. Sorry for that, but you judged it.. Hmmm vast experience with XSLT.. Great..

Can you help me again..?

Have a nice day
John

---

LarsH - Right said, I should have done all this in the first post itself, but somehow can't manage it. Now I have practiced the posting techniques and hereafter will do it correctly. :)

Also, I have accepted Martin's answer. It did the job, with little modification I got the answer for the 2nd post of mine.

Thanks a lot to all of you...

Have a nice day
John

Comment: The question is too vague to attempt a useful answer. Please show your current XSLT code. (I think you've made clear enough what result you need and what result you're currently getting.)

Comment: @LarsH: It is there, but not formatted. The OP says: "What is the right way to display the `<job>` repeatedly?" but the `<job>` isn't formatted as it should. I guess that @Martin Honnen could have edited the question. I am doing so now.

Comment: @Dimitre: having the `<job>` visible helps, but I was asking for his XSLT code.

Comment: @LarsH: Whenever someone says they only get the 1st node, it is almost 100% `<xsl:value-of>` vs. `<xsl:copy-of>` :)

Comment: @Dimitre: yeah. I just thought it would be easier to correct the problem with specifics based on the context of his code, rather than spend time making general explanations that might be difficult for him to apply -- or might not be applicable at all, if his problem is more nuanced. In principle I feel like it's a basic level of consideration, when asking "What's wrong with my code?", to show some code. I think this is borne out by John's new response, that Martin's answer didn't quite apply to his code... which he is now showing.

Comment: @LarsH: If people knew what is the best question that describes their problem, in many cases they'd be able to reach the answer themselves... Most of our job here is to help them find that best expression of the problem.

Comment: @Dimitre: I agree. And I think that starts with practically universal basics like what did you try (code), what result did you expect, and what result did you get?

Comment: @LarsH: Absolutely. Anyone who is about to post their first ever question must read this in a special first-timer's FAQ.

Comment: John, glad you were able to solve your problem. And thanks for being teachable about how to ask questions. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is that with XSLT 1.0 (or with an XSLT 2.0 processor running an XSLT 1.0 stylesheet in backwards compatible mode) the code

```
<xsl:value-of select="job"/>
```

outputs the string value of the first job element. If you want to output the value of all job elements then with XSLT 1.0 you need to use either

```
<xsl:for-each select="job">
  <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1">, </xsl:if>
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

or `<xsl:apply-templates select="job"/>` with a template for job elements e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="job">
  <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1">, </xsl:if>
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
<xsl:template>
```

while with XSLT 2.0 all you need is `<xsl:value-of select="job" separator=", "/>`.

Comment: Good job figuring out what the user meant... +1